# Which Encryption algorithm is used by EncryptByKey and EncryptByPass in Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql, azure, encryption, azure-sql-database

I want to encrypt data in azure sql database but in documentation it is not clearly mentioned that which algorithm is used by EncryptbyKey and EncryptByPassphrase.
Documentation for EncryptByPassphrase says it uses Triple DES but some people mentioned that AES is also used depending on the version of sql server. Can someone clarify ?

Also It will be helpful if someone can provide information about which algorithms are used to generate integrity bytes from authenticator.

Answer (score 2):

EncryptByKey uses whatever algorithm is specified by the [key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-symmetric-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
<algorithm> ::=  
    DES | TRIPLE_DES | TRIPLE_DES_3KEY | RC2 | RC4 | RC4_128  
    | DESX | AES_128 | AES_192 | AES_256
```

[EncryptByPassphrase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) docs say:

> Encrypt data with a passphrase using the TRIPLE DES algorithm with a
> 128 key bit length.